# Angular 1x: filter data from 2 columns only

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-1.6, angular1.6

I have query about Angular 1x.  I want to filter the below records if anything matches with title and content only. I tried giving `ng-model` to my input and applied the same like `ng-repeat= t in t.items | filter:keyword` but it is filtering the data with link and all other columns as well.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.results = [
            { title : "Cars", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler fox pixel"},
            { title : "Boats", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler cat pixel"},
            { title : "Vans", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler pig pixel"},
            { title : "Limos", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler pixel"}
        ];

    }]);
```

Is it possible to filter data from 2 just columns?

### Edit

I have a `<input type="search" />` and I want to filter data as soon as user starts typing but it should search the keywords in just two columns.

Comment: you can provide expressions to the `filter` component, or you can write your own custom comparator.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter it explains everything pretty good. For your question you can do it like:

Component's controller:

```
$scope.results = [
        { title : "Cars", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler fox pixel"},
        { title : "Boats", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler cat pixel"},
        { title : "Vans", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler pig pixel"},
        { title : "Limos", link: "http://tutorialedge.net", content: "lorem ipsum doler pixel"}
    ];

$scope.mySubstringExpression = "Vans";

$scope.myFancyFilter = function(element) {
    return element.title.indexOf(mySubstringExpression) > -1 || element.contant.indexOf(mySubstringExpression) > -1;
};
```

Then in component's template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in results | filter:myFancyFilter">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
$scope.filterResult = []
$scope.filterParams = {
    title = "all",
    content = "all"
}
$scope.filter = function (){
    if($scope.filterParams.title == "all" && $scope.filterParams.content == "all") {
        $scope.filterResult = $scope.results
    } else {
        $scope.filterResult = $scope.results.filter(x => 
            x.title == $scope.filterParams.title && 
            x.content == $scope.filterParams.content)
    }
}
```

Then you just have to use the ng-repeat over $scope.filterResult

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filterResult">
```

and you just have to use ng-model with $scope.filterParams, and every time you change the filter just call $scope.filter() and the $scope.filterResult will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using this approach

```
ng-repeat=" t in t.items | filter: {'title': 'Cars'}: true"
```